# Windows authentication on Mac OS using .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, kerberos, ntlm, kestrel

There is an application .NET Core, which is hosted on IIS in production and uses Negotiate Windows authorization (intranet). I'm trying to run it locally on Mac OS, but I can't get any local account data. Are there any alternative ways to do this on a Mac?